# Main concepts of spring security with JWT tokens (Spring boot with REST controllers)

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

**Introduction:**
I have just started using spring boot. For understanding how it works I have tried to convert my existing project (spring MVC, JSP in frontend) to spring boot approach with REST-controller and AngularJS in frontend.

**Facing problem:**
During migration I have faced to big problem with security. As I understood the best way for having good security layer now is working with JWT tokens and supporting oauth2, on which there are a lot of posts/tutorials which give different information even about basics of the security layer architecture.

**So the question is:**
Could someone point out full list of security-layer **parts/classes** which are needed for having basic (but not hello world) security features for spring boot app with REST controllers. Please don't suggest to use [stormpath](https://stormpath.com/): I want to implement it myself to get better understanding.

**Reasoning of asking this big question here:**
I have done my own investigation on this topic, but I thought that most of the links which I have checked contain a lot of bad practices, so possible incorrect architecture of security layer. so I really would like to know some kind of good practice of designing architecture of security layer.

**Details on needed features:**
I have standard list of features which I want to support.

- oauth2 support (but also to have possibility to authenticate without it)
- register request (creation of jwt token and returning to client)
- login request (acquiring jwt token if user was registered)
- logout request (releasing jwt token)
- token timeout
- multiple roles
- business rest controllers which checks for authentication and authorization (could you please give an example portion of code)
- business rest controllers which doesn't require security
- basic filtering http urls (like excluding "statics" from allowed url addresses)

**Current layers of the project:**
Below are some additional information about my current project structure:
Currently I have implemented the following modules:

- **controller:** Currently MVC controllers, but I am going to convert them to REST
- **dto:** Possibly will be changed a little bit, because of REST approach
- **model:** Will stay unchanged after conversation
- **exception:** For business logic
- **repository:** Will stay unchanged after conversation
- **service:** Possibly will be changed a little bit, because of micro-services
- **validator:** Will stay unchanged after conversation
- *other business logic modules*

If I understood correctly I will need to add two additional layers here:

- **configuration:** I have already converted some xml configurators to java-configs, but haven't touched security configurators
- **security:** I guest here will be placed authentication/authorization managers/tools. One of the goals of this question is to understand what exactly to place here.
- app class with main method in the root package (relative root)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by creating 3 projects.

1. Auth Server: This will take care of authenticating clients and users, issuing token, revoking token etc.
2. Rest API: All rest controllers, business logic, persistence layer etc.
3. Front-end: Angular JS, HTML, CSS etc.

Read about OAuth2 grant types.

We use [password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) authorization grant type when authorization server and client is developed by same organization, or when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client.

Following are the essential classes you'd need for OAuth2 implementation:

A class which extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` to configure authorization server.
Here you can configure endpoints like userDetailsService (custom class to load user data by username from database), tokenStore (to store tokens in database and perform operations on it), clientDetailsService (load client details from database; your Rest API project could be client).

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    endpoints.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    endpoints.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);
}


@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    //The expression below easies access to /oauth/check_token endpoint from the default denyAll to isAuthenticated.
    oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}


@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
}
```

A class which extends `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. Here you can configure security configuration for the resource server. Resources would be Rest controllers defined in Auth Servers (like controllers for performing CRUD operation on a user object, endpoint to revoke token; controllers which need to be in Auth Server).

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated(); //To restrict all http requests.
   /*http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll(); //Notice ant matcher here, this tells endpoints which do not require authentication. Lots of http configuration options (like applying filters, cors, csrf etc.) are available here. Please explore*/
}
```

Check out [TokenStore](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html) default implementation classes (like `JdbcTokenStore`, `JwtTokenStore`). If you'd like to use NoSQL db like Cassandra then provide custom `TokenStore` implementation.

Following is the sample code snippet for custom Token Store used for Cassandra:

```
@Override
public void storeAccessToken(final OAuth2AccessToken token, final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

    String refreshToken = null;
    if (token.getRefreshToken() != null) {
        refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken().getValue();
    }

    if (readAccessToken(token.getValue()) != null) {
        removeAccessToken(token.getValue());
    }

    final AccessTokenBuilder accessTokenBuilder = new AccessTokenBuilder();
    accessTokenRepository.save(accessTokenBuilder
                                       .withAuthenticationId(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication))
                                       .withTokenId(extractTokenKey(token.getValue()))
                                       .withTokenBody(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializeAccessToken(token)))
                                       .withUsername(authentication.getName())
                                       .withClientId(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId())
                                       .withAuthentication(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializeAuthentication(authentication)))
                                       .withRefreshTokenId(extractTokenKey(refreshToken))
                                       .build());

}


@Override
public void storeRefreshToken(final OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    final RefreshTokenBuilder refreshTokenBuilder = new RefreshTokenBuilder();
    refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshTokenBuilder
                                        .withTokenId(extractTokenKey(refreshToken.getValue()))
                                        .withTokenBody(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializeRefreshToken(refreshToken)))
                                        .withAuthentication(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializeAuthentication(authentication)))
                                        .build());
}


@Override
public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(final OAuth2AccessToken token) {
    return readAuthentication(token.getValue());
}


@Override
public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(final String token) {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = null;

    try {
        final AccessToken authAccessToken = accessTokenRepository.findByTokenId(extractTokenKey(token));
        authentication = deserializeAuthentication(authAccessToken.getAuthentication().array());
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        removeAccessToken(token);
    }

    return authentication;
}


@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(final String tokenValue) {
    final AccessToken accessToken = accessTokenRepository.findByTokenId(extractTokenKey(tokenValue));
    return accessToken != null ? deserializeAccessToken(accessToken.getTokenBody().array()) : null;
}

@Override
public OAuth2RefreshToken readRefreshToken(final String tokenValue) {
    final RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenRepository.findOne(extractTokenKey(tokenValue));
    return refreshToken != null ? deserializeRefreshToken(refreshToken.getTokenBody().array()) : null;
}


@Override
public OAuth2Authentication readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(final OAuth2RefreshToken token) {
    return readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(token.getValue());
}


OAuth2Authentication readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(final String tokenValue) {
    final RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenRepository.findOne(extractTokenKey(tokenValue));
    return refreshToken != null ? deserializeAuthentication(refreshToken.getAuthentication().array()) : null;
}


@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = null;
    final String key = authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication);
    final AccessToken accessToken = accessTokenRepository.findOne(key);
    if (accessToken != null) {
        oAuth2AccessToken = deserializeAccessToken(accessToken.getTokenBody().array());
        if (oAuth2AccessToken != null && !key.equals(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(readAuthentication(oAuth2AccessToken.getValue())))) {
            removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken.getValue());
            storeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken, authentication);
        }
    }

    return oAuth2AccessToken;
}
```

You'd need to declare repository interfaces for db operations. Interfaces which extends `CrudRepository`. For most of the DB operations we don't need to provide implementation, it is handled by Spring. For Cassandra implementation is in `SimpleCassandraRepository` class. Sample code for Access Token:

```
public interface AccessTokenRepository extends CrudRepository<AccessToken, String> {

@Query("SELECT * FROM auth_service.oauth_access_token WHERE token_id = :tokenId ALLOW FILTERING")
AccessToken findByTokenId(@Param("tokenId") String tokenId);
}
```

Sample code for `ClientDetails`

```
public interface ClientDetailsRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientDetails, String> {

}
```

Please note, we don't need to provide implementation for these interfaces. Regular CRUD queries are already implemented and taken care by Spring.

```
public interface RefreshTokenRepository extends CrudRepository<RefreshToken, String> {

}
```

**Rest API project**

Controllers declared here would get called when request received from frontend (AJAX request from javascript). All business logic and persistence layer would go here.

Here you can think about creating a module, a gateway, which talks to Auth Server. This gateway would be between your Rest API and Auth Server.
You can use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) to call remote Rest service.

If you need that not any Rest API project can make remote calls to Auth Server, then user [client_credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) as well along with `password` grant type. And, use [OAuth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) instead of `RestTemplate`. Sample code:

```
<bean id="oAuth2RestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientCredentialsResourceDetails"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultOAuth2ClientContext"/>
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="selfSignedHttpsClientFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsResourceDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails">
    <property name="accessTokenUri" value="${authentication.service.client.token.url:https://localhost:8443/oauth/token}"/>
    <property name="clientId" value="${authentication.service.client.id:testClient}"/>
    <property name="clientSecret" value="${authentication.service.client.secret:password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultOAuth2ClientContext" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DefaultOAuth2ClientContext"/>
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for sharing info about your practice. But the answer is not fully related to my question. My question was about security layer which works with JWT tokens (not with access tokens). I actually need to have security layer (not separate authentication server).

Comment: Also I have several suggesions which might be interesting for you: First of all if you have special query which cannot be generated by CrudRepository or JpaRepository, then it is always good to have "dao" layer for this kind of queries for keeping "repository" layer free from the db-syntax. Secondly if you are moving with new ideas coming from spring-boot, then it will be better to use configuration classes for creating beans (not xml configurations). Not that there are my personal opinions, I agree that there might be other coding guidelines.

Comment: I guess you have good background of knowledge, so could you please follow this question, so even if you will not give another answer, you can participate in discussion on other answers

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. In project I'm working on, XML was preferred over Annotations and that became guideline for us :). Will keep an eye on this post for more answers, it'd be a good learning.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have seen this, but here is a nice article:
https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java
. And a project on github, more or less based on that article:
https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I haven't seen these links before. They contain some information which can be helpful, but they are not fully covering my question (like the part with features) which I need. So as time for bounty is expiring, I will give it to you as the closest answer. But I will not mark your answer as accepted, for the reasons described above

Comment: Please rephrase the contents of the pages you linked to.